# Redirect Loop Laravel 5.1 in Fortrabbit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fortrabbit

I have deployed a laravel app to fortrabbit. The deployed app is a simple app just to test authentication and middleware ('auth' and 'guest'). I have tried the app in localhost, the authentication and middleware worked fine. When I tried my app in fortrabbit, the authentication worked properly but there was an issue with the middleware. I get

> This webpage has a redirect loop, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

every time I log into the home page.

`routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/','UserController@getIndex');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {

   Route::get('login','UserController@getLogin');
   Route::post('login','UserController@postLogin');

   Route::get('register','UserController@getRegister');
   Route::post('register','UserController@postRegister');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

   Route::get('home','MainController@getHome');
   Route::get('logout','MainController@logout');

});
```

`Authenticate.php` for 'auth' middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else{
            return redirect()->guest('/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

`RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` for 'guest' middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Is there any file/setting in fortrabbit that I have to configure to run this app properly?

Comment: Your auth middleware looks off to me. If guest() do this, if not guest redirect to login. Shouldn't you be redirected to login if you are a guest on a page where guests are not allowed? You're in an endless loop because once you login, you are no longer a guest, so you get redirected to 'home', which triggers the 'auth' that's off and redirects you to login, which triggers 'guest' which redirects you ...

Comment: Hi I think this is a session bug https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172 can you try a clean install again? what are the session drivers set into in fort rabbit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying `config/cache.php` with Fortrabbit memcache configuration ([link](https://help.fortrabbit.com/install-laravel-5#toc-memcache)), we should change not only the value of `CACHE_DRIVER` but also the `SESSION_DRIVER` to `memcached` in `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

Your auth middleware looks off to me.
If guest() do this, if not guest redirect to login. Shouldn't you be redirected to login if you are a guest on a page where guests are not allowed?
You're in an endless loop because once you login, you are no longer a guest, so you get redirected to 'home', which triggers the 'auth' that's off and redirects you to login, which triggers 'guest' which redirects you ...

I think you're auth middleware should look like this, source from [Laravel on Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I have changed the else statement to `return redirect()->guest('/login');` and the result is still the same

Comment: @neemo Could you upload the Authenticate.php file, I think the issue is a misplaced bracket.

Comment: I have re-uploaded the app with the updated Authenticate.php (updated above) to [mylara.frb.io](http://mylara.frb.io) and still, unsolved.

Comment: @neemo, I meant upload it so I can download and inspect the Authenticate.php file

Comment: you can download it [here](http://http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1191647)

Comment: @neemo, your file seems to be fine, it must've been a typo in your questions code.
I get a "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53"  when I try to login or register. 
Add this in your forms: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: I have added `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` too as I use Form facade on the login page `{!! Form::open(['url' => '/login']) !!}` that automatically create csrf_token on the form. I guess there is/are certain file/files that I have to configure regarding the authentication in fortrabbit. I am still trying to figure it out

Comment: can you do a dd($request) at the very top of login function in controller?

Comment: @Gokigooooks I have re-uploaded the app with dd($request) function on the login.

Comment: [SOLVED] after modifying `config/cache.php` with Fortrabbit memcache configuration ([link is here](https://help.fortrabbit.com/install-laravel-5#toc-memcache)) , we should change not only the value of `CACHE_DRIVER` but also the `SESSION_DRIVER` to `memcached` in `.env` file